# Auto Count Date/Time in Mongodb/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose in my nodejs/expressjs application to interact with mongodb, below is one of the mongodb collection or schema where I have "raisedon" document or field which I have set to Date type, It is updated to to current date whenever a user raises a request on client side, similarly I have "approvedon" and "rejectedon" documents set to Type Date, which also will get updated to current date when someone approves or rejects a request, I want these three fields to get auto counted or similar three fields synchronous to those three which will start counting days and time after the users raise the requests, approves or rejects for each seperate, which I want because after some certain time I have to make auto send emails if no user approves or rejects, or on some other condition, I tried to convert the raised on date value to milliseconds and tried to add certain time in milliseconds and compare those two and sending mail based on condition, but the values are returning as NaN, so I'm quite unable to wrap around how to achieve the logic, can someone help me to find a solution please

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var Requests = new Schema({
id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    request: String,
    description: String,
    approval: Boolean,
    rejection: Boolean,
    expired: Boolean,
    raisedon: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    approvedon: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    rejectedon: {type: Date, default: Date.now} 
  });
```

module.exports = mongoose.model('Requests', Requests);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve the mail sending logic after certain period from request raised time as below

```
var Requests = require('./process');
var escmail = require('./escalationmail');
var escalation = function () {

Requests.find('', function (err, data) {




    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var raisd = data[i]['raisedon'];
        var time1 = raisd.setTime(raisd.getTime() + 7*24*60*60000);
        var time2 = new Date();
        var time3 = time2.setTime(time2.getTime());
        if (data[i]['expired'] == "0") {
            if (time3 > time2) {
                escmail.sendMails();

                Requests.findByIdAndUpdate(data[i]['_id'], {
                        expired: "1"
                    },
                    function (err) {



                        console.log("escalated emails have been sent");

                    })


            }

        }

    }
})
```

}

exports.escalation = escalation;

Answer (score 0):

`Date.now` is a function, so when you coerce it to a `Number`, it becomes `NaN`.  Just change those calls to `Date.now()`.

Comment: I changed to Date.now(), but still in console.log, the raisedon is logged as Tue Feb 11 2014 11:36:21, before changing also it was the same

Comment: `Date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).  Not exactly sure what you're asking at this point....

Comment: Mongoose docs example uses Date.now http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html , I just wanted mails to be sent automatically to users after 7 days from request initialized date if no action is taken by any user on that request(like approve or reject) in my node.js application I'm developing